# alterar a distancia entre a barra e o eixo Y no r

Tags: r, ggplot2

Como posso alterar a distancia das barras em relaçao ao eixo y usando o ggplot?

utilizando o código:

```
k <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
j <- c(3,5,8,1,2,6)

df <- data.frame(k,j)

ggplot(df, aes(y=reorder(k, -j), x=j))+
  geom_col(fill="#70A2E7",  width = 0.85)+
  theme_bw(10)
```

grafico
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A opção `expand` das `scales` existe para isso. Pode ser usada com a função `expansion` para maior controle:

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(j, reorder(k, -j))) +
  geom_col(fill="#70A2E7", width = 0.85) +
  theme_bw(10)

# Distância aditiva (adiciona espaço na mesma escala dos dados plotados)
p + scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(add = c(0, 0.5)))

# Distância multiplicativa (adiciona espaço proporcional, p.e. 0.1 para 10%)
p + scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.1, 0.2)))
```